# 投稿へのコメントを投稿のshowページへ遷移せずに、表示させたい。

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery, rails-activerecord, facebook

#### 前提・実現したいこと

投稿へのコメントを投稿のshowページへ遷移せずに、表示させたい。

【理想図】
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

【現状図】
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

#### 発生している問題・エラーメッセージ

ホーム画面(Page#index)のフィード(自分の投稿とフォローしている人の投稿)から、
それぞれの投稿(@micropost)のidをPage#index内で取得できないです。

【page_controller.rb】

```
class PageController < ApplicationController

  def index
   @micropost = current_user.microposts.build
   @feed_items = current_user.feed.paginate(page: params[:page])
   @micropost = Micropost.find(params[:id])★エラーでます。
   @micropost = Micropost.includes(:user).find(params[:id])★エラーでます。
   @comments = @micropost.comments.includes(:user).all
   @comment = @micropost.comments.build(user_id: current_user.id) if current_user
    ・
    ・
 end
```

【エラー内容】

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in PageController#index
Couldn't find Micropost without an ID




@micropost = Micropost.find(params[:id])
@micropost = Micropost.includes(:user).find(params[:id])
```

#### 該当のソースコード

【index.html.erb】

```
<!-- タイムライン -->
<h3>Micropost Feed</h3>
<%= render 'shared/feed' %> →_micropost.html.erbを呼び出します。
```

【_micropost.html.erb】

```
<li id="micropost-<%= micropost.id %>">

                       ・
                       ・
                       ・

            <dd>
            <!-- コメント -->
            <div>
                <%= render 'comments/array' %> ←@commentを表示するパーシャルです。
                <%= render 'calls/array' %>
                <%= render 'says/array' %>
                <%= render 'insists/array' %>
            </div>
            </dd>
        </dl>
                       ・
                       ・
                       ・


</li>

【calls/_array.html.erb】
<% @comments. each do |comment| %>
    <div>
        <strong><%= user_name(comment, @user) %></strong>
        </br>
        <p><%= body(comment) %></p>
            <% if user_signed_in? && comment.user == current_user %>
            <p><%= link_to 'Delete', comment_path(comment), method: :delete %></p>
            <% end %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

#### 補足情報(言語/FW/ツール等のバージョンなど)

・アコーディオンメニューは各投稿に設定してあり、
各投稿にコメントを投稿し、投稿を表示させたいです。
現状、コメントの投稿はできています。(データベース確認済み)
しかし、コメントの表示ができません。
おそらく、@micropostを正しくpage#indexに置いていないため、@micropostに紐づいた@commentを表示できない、ということだと思います(*´Д｀)

#### 追加

【試したコード】

●page#index

```
@microposts = current_user.feed.includes(:comments)
```

●user.rb←自分と自分がフォローしているユーザーの投稿を取得する。(モデルを分けてますのでコードが多くなりました。)

```
  def feed
    following_ids = "SELECT followed_id FROM relationships WHERE follower_id = :user_id"
    associate_shops_ids = "SELECT shop_id FROM associates WHERE user_id = :user_id"
    evaluate_microposts_ids = "SELECT micropost_id FROM evaluates WHERE user_id = (#{following_ids})"
    praise_microposts_ids = "SELECT micropost_id FROM praises WHERE user_id = (#{following_ids})"
    Micropost.where("user_id IN (#{following_ids}) OR shop_id IN (#{associate_shops_ids}) OR id IN (#{evaluate_microposts_ids})
                                                   OR id IN (#{praise_microposts_ids}) OR user_id = :user_id", user_id: id)
  end
```

●index.html.erb

```
<%= render partial: 'microposts/micropost', collection: @microposts %>
```

●_micropost.html.erb

```
<%= render partial: 'comments/array', collection: micropost.comments %>
```

●comments/_array.html.erb

```
<%= comment.id %>
```

【エラー内容】

```
undefined local variable or method `comment' for #<#<Class:0x007fed87643850>:0x007fed875ce6e0>
```

マルチポスト http://qa.atmarkit.co.jp/q/10092 と
https://teratail.com/questions/55375

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/55375

Answer (score 0, accepted):

データから直接持ってくる場合

```
def comment_feed(micropost)
  comments = micropost.comments #その投稿のidに紐づくcommentを全て取得します。
  # commentを1つずつ取り出し、bodyの内容でpタグを出力する
  comments.map do |comment|
    content_tag(:p, comment.body)
  end
end
```

teratailで解答をいただきました。
https://teratail.com/questions/55698

Answer (score 2):

なんかいろいろ `build` してますけど、

- `User has_many :microposts`
- `Micropost has_many :comments`

の既存データを表示するのなら以下のような感じでよいのでは?

pages_controller.rb

```
def index
  @microposts = current_user.microposts.includes(:comments)
end
```

index.html.erb

```
<%= render partial: 'micropost', collection: @microposts %>
```

_micropost.html.erb

```
<%= micropost.id %>
<%= render partial: 'comment', collection: micropost.comments %>
```

_comment.html.erb

```
<%= comment.id %>
```

Comment: @sakuroさん
ありがとうございます。  

質問文で情報が抜けていましたが、回答していただいたコードは自分以外の投稿へのコメントも表示できますでしょうか？  

質問文に情報を追加したのですが、フィードには自分・自分がフォローしているユーザーの投稿を表示するようにしています。  

さらに、ユーザーはUserとShopの2つ、そこからコメントのモデルを4つ作っています。Commentはそのコメントモデル4つのうちの一つとなっています。  

回答していただいたコードを試したところ、「質問の情報追加部分」のようなエラーが発生しました。  

おそらく、これはコメントモデルを4つに分けているために、
CommentがMicropostすべてにあるわけではないからできない、といったメッセージだと思うのです！

Comment: データベースから直接もってこようかと思います。
http://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/30507/%E5%90%84%E6%8A%95%E7%A8%BF%E3%81%AEid%E3%82%92%E5%8F%96%E5%BE%97%E3%81%97-where%E3%81%A7%E6%A4%9C%E7%B4%A2%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B%E6%96%B9%E6%B3%95