# 各投稿のidを取得し、whereで検索する方法。

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, sqlite

**前提・実現したいこと**
ホームのタイムラインの投稿にそれぞれコメントを表示したいです。

こんな感じです。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

**発生している問題・エラーメッセージ**

コメント欄に以下の文字が現れます。。。

```
#<Comment::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x007f1be23fc168>
```

**該当のソースコード**

【microposts_helper.rb】

```
def comment_feed(micropost)
  @id = micropost.id ←その投稿のidを取得します。
  Comment.where(:@id)←その投稿のidに紐づくcommentを全て取得します。
end
```

【_micropost.html.erb】

```
<%= comment_feed(micropost) %>←取得したコメントを表示します。
```

【micropost.rb】

```
  has_many :comments
```

【comment.rb】

```
belongs_to :micropost
```

**補足情報(言語/FW/ツール等のバージョンなど)**
ユーザーモデルはUserとShopの2種類です。
さらに各ユーザー間同士でコメントのモデルを分けていますので、コメントモデルは4つあり、その一つがCommentになります。

どうしても、うまくいかず先に進めません。
何卒よろしくお願いします。

マルチポスト
[teratail](https://teratail.com/questions/55698?modal=q-comp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

【自己解決】

```
def comment_feed(micropost)
  comments = micropost.comments #その投稿のidに紐づくcommentを全て取得します。
  # commentを1つずつ取り出し、bodyの内容でpタグを出力する
  comments.map do |comment|
    content_tag(:p, comment.body)
  end
end
```